# Where to download rasters for QGIS 2.6

Tags: raster, qgis-2, imagery

Where can I download sat imagery. I've read that OpenLayers provide such things but it requires an internet connexion, and I mostly use QGIS with an offline computer. So do you know a way/provider (for free) for such products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Landsat imagery via [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). That is quite low resolution.

Another global dataset is [BlueMarble](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484), which is very nice, and is low res too, but globally that makes for a gigantic dataset.

More locally, you could contact your municipal government, or state government, and see if they'll allow you to download an image, which could be high resolution (up to 0.1 m resolution). But usually they'll want to charge you.

Comment: Thanks for the sources! By any chances, do you know if there's a way to import some scenery from google earth?

Comment: I think that Google Earth Pro (which is free now) allows you to export georeferenced images, but you'll have to read their conditions of use to see if you're allowed to use it for what you want to do.

Comment: I did create an account with googlearth pro but didn't find where this features was. Even not sure it still exists. As speaking of it, I ll have a look tomorrow once more. I keep in touch'

Comment: Well, with google earth pro I'm able to capture screen content but at current scale. I thought I would be able to capture large area of "HD tiles" but it's not working that way.I kindly thank you for your help.